# How to best transform a SparkSQL Dataframe Array[String] column to a new [String] column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to Spark and I have a Apache SparkSQL `DataFrame df` with 4 columns, having this schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- _title: string (nullable = false)
 |-- _published-at: date (nullable = false)
 |-- p: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

`df` contains lots (a million or so) of news articles with columns containing, for each record: unique id (_id), title (_title), publish date (_published-at), and a String array of the text *paragraphs* in each article (p).

I now would like to transform the "p" column from its current format `Array[String]` of article paragraphs to a fused `String` of the full article text, where the transformation is a simple mapping where the paragraph elements are concatenated with space (" ") between them, resulting in a new fifth `String` column added to `df`. I.e. something like this:

```
df.withColumn(df.(col"p").map(_.mkString(" ")).alias("fullarticle"))
```

which does not work. It seems to be a trivial problem however, but I must have got something wrong. In Spark's `functions` package, many functions can be found, but none seems to be suitable here. Must I use a "User Defined Functions" (UDF) in some way? The best would be to avoid it, if possible.

It IS possible to  transform this to `String` resulting in a new `Dataset[String] dsFullArticles` by doing:

```
dsFullArticles = df.select(col("p").as[Array[String]]).map(_.mkString(" ")).alias("fullarticle")
```

(the `.as[Array[String]]` seems to be needed to unwrap the `WrappedArray` that actually wraps each `Array[String]` element in the "p" column). But how to instead append `dsFullArticles` as a new *column* to `df`?

Thereafter, I would also like to find the length of the longest word for each article in the "fullarticle" column, and add it as a sixth column to `df`:

```
// Split each article in an array of its words
val dsFullArticlesArrayOfWords = dsFullArticles.map(s => s.split(" "))
// Find number of characters of longest word in article, 0 if article is empty
val dsMaxWordLength =
  dsFullArticlesArrayOfWords.map(s => (s.map(w => w.length()) match {
    case x if x.isEmpty => 0  
    case x => x.max
  }))
```

The above code works as well, producing a `Dataset[int]` , but how to, similarly, add it as a column to `df`? The same problem here. When having all in the same `DataFrame df`, it would be easy to do various SQL selections, filtering etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/#concat_ws) function:

> concat_ws(sep, [str | array(str)]+) - Returns the concatenation of the strings separated by sep.

In your case:

```
df.withColumn("fullarticle", concat_ws(" ",col("p")))
```

Comment: Thanks @galando, it worked! I have looked at the `concat_ws` function before, but I only thought it could be used to horizontally concatenate `Column`s like several  `String` columns to one new `String` column, not a single `Array[String]` column to a `String` column.